# EF Core with linkqkit cannot translate EF.Functions.DateDiffDay in Sum() method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linqkit

I'm using the LinkqKit library and getting an error when I try to translate this code:

```html
public static Expression<Func<Unit, int>> CalculateTimer()
{
  return x => x.Statuses.Sum(s => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(x.CreatedAt, DateTime.UtcNow));
}
```

The error says

> Translation of method 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions.DateDiffDay' failed

Hovewer without Sum it works just fine

```html
public static Expression<Func<Unit, int>> CalculateTimer()
{
  return x => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(x.CreatedAt, DateTime.UtcNow);
}
```

Also it works just fine (with Sum) when not using LinkqKit

Comment: how did you use the linqkit? is this ef for .net framework or ef core? did you call `.AsExpandable()`?

Comment: Show how do use this function in real query.

Comment: Ok, I need to say that it seems not to work even without linkqkit (idk how I missed that)

x => new Dto
            {

                Timers = new Times
                {
                    ImplementationStage = x.Statuses.Sum(s => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(x.CreatedAt, x.CreatedAt))
                }
            }

Comment: @Nikita are you using ef core earlier than 8? i reckon older ef core only support small set of sql functions.